# java.nio.file.Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options) disappears the file from source

Tags: java, nio

I am using java.nio.file.Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options) method to move file from source to destination on Windows as well as Linux.

**Code :**

```
 public void purgeProcessedFile(File xmlFile, String fileDestination) {
        logger.info("Started purging.");
        File directory = new File(fileDestination);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        File destFile = new File(fileDestination + File.separator + xmlFile.getName());
        logger.info("XML file path is : " + xmlFile.getPath());
        logger.info("dest File path is : " + destFile.getPath());
        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            //if (xmlFile.renameTo(destFile)) {
            try {
                Files.move(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(xmlFile.getPath()),
                        FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(destFile.getPath()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //throw LoggedException.wrap(logger, "Unexpected IOException", e);
                logger.info("File purging failed.");
                logger.error(e);
            }
            logger.info("File purged successfully.");
            /* } else {
                 logger.info("File purging failed.");
             }*/
        } else {
            logger.info("File with same name already exists at destination folder: " + fileDestination);
        }

        logger.info("Ended purging.");
    }
```

**Expected result :**

File to be moved to destination directory.

**Actual result:**

File is getting deleted from source and not moving to destination directory.

**in logs**

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:  source location.
```

is getting thrown.

As this is platform independent expectation is to be able to work on both windows and Linux.

Comment: Are you sure about the presence of source file? Error says "No Such File" for source.

Comment: @Santosh yes, i have put the file in source location. i am sure about it.

Comment: You should be able to turn that code into an MCVE ... so that other people can try to run it.

Comment: @Stephen C well this method is where i am getting issue, and i am not sure what more i can add here?

Comment: If you turn it into an MVCE, **other people** will be able to **run** it.   Got it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably `FileSystems.getDefault()` which is not valid for the net drive.
In the new `Path/Paths/Files` style:

```
public void purgeProcessedFile(File xmlFile, String fileDestination) {
    Path destFile = Paths.get(fileDestination, xmlFile.getName());
    Path directory = destFile.getParent();
    if (!Files.exist(directory)) {
        Files.createDirectories(directory);
    }
    if (!Files.exists(destFile)) {
        try {
            Files.move(xmlFile.toPath(), destFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("File with same name already exists at destination folder: "
                + fileDestination);
    }
}
```

That saying, I would expect the disappeared files to reside on the local computer in a directory created, maybe something like C:/F/My/XML/Data.

Comment: destFile.getPath() and xmLFile.getPath() return string, however move method requires Path Type argument.

Comment: Sorry, copy error, corrected. xmlFile. **to**Path: to change the File to a Path.

Comment: Now it should be allright. Was confused a bit on fileDestination.

Comment: The method exist(Path) is undefined for the type Files this compiler error is being thrown

Comment: Also The method exists() is undefined for the type Path compiler error

Comment: Sorry, did change it to Files.exists at on place, not the other.